# Azure Sql DataBase with python in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, sql, azure, azure-data-factory

Hello im new in Azure Sql DataBase (i have the database already in azure SQL database) . I have experience in Data Science with python and i would like to import Data from Azure SQL Database with Python and visual studio Code but i dont know how. i dont find any script for this . Someone can help me?

Comment: Do you want to know import data from Azure SQL database in data factory with python?

Comment: yes with python in Visual Studio Code

Comment: Hi @emanuel lemos, If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We can't help you build the whole script codes, but can give some suggestions.

1. Please ref this tutorial: [Quickstart: Create a data factory and
   pipeline using Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-python#create-a-linked-service) to create the Data Factory, pipeline.
2. Using this API to create the linked service for Azure SQL
   [database:AzureSqlDatabaseLinkedService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-datafactory/azure.mgmt.datafactory.models.azuresqldatabaselinkedservice?view=azure-python)
3. Create the Azure SQL database dataset: [AzureSqlTableDataset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-datafactory/azure.mgmt.datafactory.models.azuresqltabledataset?view=azure-python)

I think help you create the script which import Data from Azure SQL Database with Python.

HTH.